# Looking for assistance with Bash script for checking if updates are available in lubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I am looking for a simple script that i can use in a bash file to check if there are any system updates available.

I started with

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
updates=$(apt list upgradeable)
if [-n ${updates} ]; then
echo "updates available"
else
echo "no updates!"
fi
```

However, the problem is that even if there is no updates, you still get a return of "Listing... Done"

Look forward to any help or advise.

Cheers,
Darren

Answer (score 1):

The obvious option is to get rid if the line starting with `Listing`; `apt` also gives a warning when the STDOUT is not a TTY, so you want to get rid of that line too:

```
updates=$(apt list upgradeable |& grep -Ev '^(Listing|WARNING)')
```

`grep -Ev '^(Listing|WARNING)'` does the mentioned work.

Comment: Thank you heemayl - that has helped to get a step closer...  No i am getting false positives with the script in its current form.

Comment: Note that the 'apt' command's man page specifically calls out that it isn't meant for scripting. So this might not be a good long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aptitude for that.

```
aptitude -q -F%p --disable-columns search "~U"
```